Docs for the new MathML support in InDesign?
All my research keeps taking me back to https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/math-expressions.html.
Where can I find a detailed list of supported features? Does one exist yet?

Maybe start here: https://www.w3.org/Math/

Thanks for the input. I am looking for docs on how to use MathML in InDesign. This is all I could find on w3.org/Math.

As far as I know, Adobe has no documentation on how to use MathML itself. It was not developed by Adobe, and they likely assume users are familiar with MathML and how to use it, and what it is, and how to generate it. All they have done in InDesign is to create a method to render MathML code within InDesign - a way to input the code, and render it on a page.
There are however links to various introductions on MathML, which describe what it is, and there are tutorials on how to write it manually, links to various other resources, and links to MathML authoring software which are all listed on the W3C MathML website.
You can write MathML code directly in Indesign's MathML Input Section where you can edit and preview it. Obviously this assumes you know how to code in MathML or already have some valid MathML code to use.
Alternatively, if you're not up for coding it yourself, you can also use 3rd party authoring software such as for example LibreOffice Math, where you can type in your equation and save as MathML, then open the text file in any text editor, and copy and paste the code directly into InDesign's MathML Input Section.  It looks like MathMagic which you linked to is a similar equation editor which can output MathML, however I'm not familiar with it.
I don't know if Adobe has plans to create a tool or plugin, or if one already exists, which can generate MathML code for you. As far as I can tell, you can only input the code.
Anyway, regarding LibreOffice, there's a PDF guide book to using the included Math equation editor.
Here's a sample equation so you can test it. I don't have InDesign installed at the moment, so I can't test it myself.
The LibreOffice Math equation I typed in was f(x,y) = {func e^{M} cdot sqrt{cos(x) + tan(y) } } over {M^{2}}
From LibreOffice Math, save as MathML (.mml) results in this code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
 <semantics>
  <mrow>
   <mi>f</mi>
   <mrow>
    <mrow>
     <mo fence="true" form="prefix" stretchy="false">(</mo>
     <mrow>
      <mrow>
       <mi>x</mi>
       <mi>,</mi>
       <mi>y</mi>
      </mrow>
     </mrow>
     <mo fence="true" form="postfix" stretchy="false">)</mo>
    </mrow>
    <mo stretchy="false">=</mo>
    <mfrac>
     <mrow>
      <msup>
       <mi mathvariant="normal">e</mi>
       <mi>M</mi>
      </msup>
      <mo stretchy="false">⋅</mo>
      <msqrt>
       <mrow>
        <mi>cos</mi>
        <mrow>
         <mrow>
          <mo fence="true" form="prefix" stretchy="false">(</mo>
          <mrow>
           <mi>x</mi>
          </mrow>
          <mo fence="true" form="postfix" stretchy="false">)</mo>
         </mrow>
         <mo stretchy="false">+</mo>
         <mi>tan</mi>
        </mrow>
        <mrow>
         <mo fence="true" form="prefix" stretchy="false">(</mo>
         <mrow>
          <mi>y</mi>
         </mrow>
         <mo fence="true" form="postfix" stretchy="false">)</mo>
        </mrow>
       </mrow>
      </msqrt>
     </mrow>
     <msup>
      <mi>M</mi>
      <mn>2</mn>
     </msup>
    </mfrac>
   </mrow>
  </mrow>
  <annotation encoding="StarMath 5.0">f(x,y) = {func e^{M} cdot sqrt{cos(x) + tan(y) } } over {M^{2}}</annotation>
 </semantics>
</math>

Here's the resulting MML file viewed in my browser (Firefox). Theoretically you could copy and paste the code above into InDesign's MathML Input Section, and get the same result.


Thank you for the thorough answer. My understanding is that the current introductory MathML support in InDesign is rather limited. I was hoping to find some detailed documentation of InDesign's current limitations. Unfortunately, it seems such a list does not exist yet.
